# How to perform system migration to a smaller drive using the unix/linux tool dd?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd, unix, migration

I am trying to migrate a windows 10 from a 1TB HDD to a 256GB SSD, and I want to use the easiest free way with dd (the Linux/UNIX clone tool)

I do have the source drive partitions shrunk such that they are smaller than the target's space, and it is unallocated space after it in the source drive. There were EFI FAT32 partition and windows 10 OS NTFS partition

I have done it in the past where the target drive is bigger than the source, so the only thing I did after `dd if=/dev/sd<source> of=/dev/sd<target>` was simply expanding the partition in windows' diskmgmt.msc

However, I am not sure if it is safe to do the similar way when the target drive is smaller than the source drive. (while the payload in the source is smaller than the target so that)

Any advice is appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/sda` is the entire drive. I'm not sure if you want to copy/clone the partition-table and master-bootrecord. `/dev/sda1` `/dev/sda2` etc. are the partitions. You can create dd images for each partition and restore accordingly to your SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a straight DD of /dev/sdX as you did last time. It will work fine as you have already resized the partitions - provided you have the free space at the end of the disk.  You will probably get an error about not being able to write to the disk when its done - you can ignore this.

(You might want to investigate using ddrescue or pv to do the copy - they provide progress feedback which is harder to get from DD).